# Android NDK clang undefined reference to 'memcpy', version 'GLIBC_2.2.5'

Tags: android-ndk, clang, grpc, glibc

I'm trying to compile the grpc project using Android NDK, for the android-x86_64 ABI I'm getting the following error:

```
/Users/someuser/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/21.1.6352462/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin/ld: error: symbol memcpy has undefined version GLIBC_2.2.5
/Users/someuser/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/21.1.6352462/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/bits/fortify/string.h:62: error: undefined reference to 'memcpy', version 'GLIBC_2.2.5'
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

This is reproducing on Windows/Ubuntu/MacOS.
The Android NDK doesn't contain the gcc compiler anymore, how can this be solved?

```
$ /Users/someuser/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/21.1.6352462/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/x86_64-linux-android24-clang++ --target=x86_64-none-linux-android24 --sysroot=/Users/someuser/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/21.1.6352462/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/sysroot -fPIC -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security    -O2 -DNDEBUG  -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc_real.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libatomic.a -static-libstdc++ -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--no-undefined -Qunused-arguments  -shared -Wl,-soname,libgpr.so -o libgpr.so CMakeFiles/gpr.dir/src/core/lib/gpr/alloc.cc.o CMakeFiles/gpr.dir/src/core/lib/gpr/atm.cc.o CMakeFiles/gpr.dir/src/core/lib/gpr/cpu_iphone.cc.o CMakeFiles/gpr.dir/src/core/lib/gpr/cpu_linux.cc.o CMakeFiles/gpr.dir/src/core/lib/gpr/cpu_posix.cc.o CMakeFiles/gpr.dir/src/core/lib/gpr/cpu_windows.cc.o CMakeFiles/gpr.dir/src/core/lib/gpr/env_linux.cc.o CMakeFiles/gpr.dir/src/core/lib/gpr/env_posix.cc.o CMakeFiles/gpr.dir/src/core/lib/gpr/env_windows.cc.o CMakeFiles/gpr.dir/src/core/lib/gpr/log.cc.o CMakeFiles/gpr.dir/src/core/lib/gpr/log_android.cc.o CMakeFiles/gpr.dir/src/core/lib/gpr/log_linux.cc.o CMakeFiles/gpr.dir/src/core/lib/gpr/log_posix.cc.o CMakeFiles/gpr.dir/src/core/lib/gpr/log_windows.cc.o CMakeFiles/gpr.dir/src/core/lib/gpr/murmur_hash.cc.o CMakeFiles/gpr.dir/src/core/lib/gpr/string.cc.o CMakeFiles/gpr.dir/src/core/lib/gpr/string_posix.cc.o CMakeFiles/gpr.dir/src/core/lib/gpr/string_util_windows.cc.o CMakeFiles/gpr.dir/src/core/lib/gpr/string_windows.cc.o CMakeFiles/gpr.dir/src/core/lib/gpr/sync.cc.o CMakeFiles/gpr.dir/src/core/lib/gpr/sync_abseil.cc.o CMakeFiles/gpr.dir/src/core/lib/gpr/sync_posix.cc.o CMakeFiles/gpr.dir/src/core/lib/gpr/sync_windows.cc.o CMakeFiles/gpr.dir/src/core/lib/gpr/time.cc.o CMakeFiles/gpr.dir/src/core/lib/gpr/time_posix.cc.o CMakeFiles/gpr.dir/src/core/lib/gpr/time_precise.cc.o CMakeFiles/gpr.dir/src/core/lib/gpr/time_windows.cc.o CMakeFiles/gpr.dir/src/core/lib/gpr/tls_pthread.cc.o CMakeFiles/gpr.dir/src/core/lib/gpr/tmpfile_msys.cc.o CMakeFiles/gpr.dir/src/core/lib/gpr/tmpfile_posix.cc.o CMakeFiles/gpr.dir/src/core/lib/gpr/tmpfile_windows.cc.o CMakeFiles/gpr.dir/src/core/lib/gpr/wrap_memcpy.cc.o CMakeFiles/gpr.dir/src/core/lib/gprpp/arena.cc.o CMakeFiles/gpr.dir/src/core/lib/gprpp/examine_stack.cc.o CMakeFiles/gpr.dir/src/core/lib/gprpp/fork.cc.o CMakeFiles/gpr.dir/src/core/lib/gprpp/global_config_env.cc.o CMakeFiles/gpr.dir/src/core/lib/gprpp/host_port.cc.o CMakeFiles/gpr.dir/src/core/lib/gprpp/mpscq.cc.o CMakeFiles/gpr.dir/src/core/lib/gprpp/stat_posix.cc.o CMakeFiles/gpr.dir/src/core/lib/gprpp/stat_windows.cc.o CMakeFiles/gpr.dir/src/core/lib/gprpp/thd_posix.cc.o CMakeFiles/gpr.dir/src/core/lib/gprpp/thd_windows.cc.o CMakeFiles/gpr.dir/src/core/lib/gprpp/time_util.cc.o CMakeFiles/gpr.dir/src/core/lib/profiling/basic_timers.cc.o CMakeFiles/gpr.dir/src/core/lib/profiling/stap_timers.cc.o  -ldl -lm third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/status/libabsl_status.so third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/synchronization/libabsl_synchronization.so -landroid -llog third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/strings/libabsl_str_format_internal.so third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/strings/libabsl_cord.so third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/types/libabsl_bad_optional_access.so third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/debugging/libabsl_stacktrace.so third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/debugging/libabsl_symbolize.so third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/debugging/libabsl_debugging_internal.so third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/debugging/libabsl_demangle_internal.so third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/synchronization/libabsl_graphcycles_internal.so third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/time/libabsl_time.so third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/strings/libabsl_strings.so third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/strings/libabsl_strings_internal.so third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/base/libabsl_throw_delegate.so third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/numeric/libabsl_int128.so third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/time/libabsl_civil_time.so third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/time/libabsl_time_zone.so third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/base/libabsl_malloc_internal.so third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/base/libabsl_base.so third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/base/libabsl_spinlock_wait.so third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/base/libabsl_raw_logging_internal.so third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/base/libabsl_log_severity.so -pthread -latomic -lm
/Users/someuser/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/21.1.6352462/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin/ld: error: symbol memcpy has undefined version GLIBC_2.2.5
/Users/someuser/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/21.1.6352462/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/bits/fortify/string.h:62: error: undefined reference to 'memcpy', version 'GLIBC_2.2.5'
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Have you solved the problem yet?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to comment out `__asm__(".symver memcpy,memcpy@GLIBC_2.2.5");` from the grpc code.